# Swift location updates in background - is it possible to execute method immediately?

Tags: ios, core-location

Im developing an app and I want to have a feature that sends push notification when user leaves predefined region. For tracking the process of leaving Im gonna use CLCircularRegion and Parse for notifications. The question is - can the app execute methods of sending push when it is in background state? I know that there is a permission available, which allows to monitor location update always and I also know about delegate, which can be used on location update.

The actual question is does it really work when app in background state? The book *iOS 8 Swift Programming Cookbook* says that location delegate messages are not delivered normally to application, but instead they are delivered in a batch when application again becomes the foreground application. Otherwise, the Apple documentation says that the app becomes awake when location changes.

Say, user terminated app day before and on the next day he left region defined in CLCircularRegion. Will delegate trigger and fire up the method of sending push?

Comment: Have you tried? Note that "in the background" and "terminated" are not quite the same thing, though, especially if user-terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Region monitoring will trigger updates even if the app is in the background.  Your app could respond to the region monitoring callbacks `didEnterRegion:`, `didExitRegion:` to then trigger the desired push notifications as appropriate.

Per Apple:

> In iOS, regions associated with your app are tracked at all times, including when the app isn’t running. If a region boundary is crossed while an app isn’t running, that app is relaunched into the background to handle the event. Similarly, if the app is suspended when the event occurs, it’s woken up and given a short amount of time (around 10 seconds) to handle the event. When necessary, an app can request more background execution time using the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` method of the UIApplication class.

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW1